# After istikhara dua, if something happens to make my goals easier, is it a positive sign?

Tags: istikharah

I hope to gain some insight into istikhara signs after dua.
I made an istikhara last night on something this morning something happened to make my goals for the thing I prayed iatikhara for easier. 
Can one interpret that as a positive sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, yes it is a positive sign. Usually after istekhara you find it easy to attain the goal or there come such situations that you let go of it

Comment: Jazakallah khairun

Answer (score 2):

when we perform istikhara we depend on Allah (Swt) to make the decision on behalf of us. So when we proceed to do a task then if Allah find that out good for us then He will ease that task for us otherwise obstacles will be their.

Tanslation of istikhara Dua is given:
TRANSLATION: "O Allah! I seek goodness from Your Knowledge and with Your Power (and Might) I seek strength, and I ask from You Your Great Blessings, because You have the Power and I do not have the power. You Know everything and I do not know, and You have knowledge of the unseen. Oh Allah! If in Your Knowledge this action (which I intend to do) is better for my religion and faith, for my life and end [death], for here [in this world] and the hereafter then make it destined for me and make it easy for me and then add blessings [baraka'] in it, for me. O Allah! In Your Knowledge if this action is bad for me, bad for my religion and faith, for my life and end [death], for here [in this world] and the hereafter then turn it away from me and turn me away from it and whatever is better for me, ordain [destine] that for me and then make me satisfied with it."

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. For example to learn what we expect answers to look like you may read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,

Yes, you may interpret it as a positive sign, but know that your answer to an istikhara isn't always going to become manifest in your life. You will NOT necessarily see a dream/vision/sign/etc. Allāh ﷻ will place a bit of inclination in your heart towards going through with the action or not [(source)](https://www.istikhara.com/)

Comment: Instead of sharing the link of your website (promotion) it would be better to link a source to support your claims!

Comment: @Medi1Saif, this better? I'm new to the site, thanks for the patience.

Comment: I'm no mod by I don't see much improvement as the link do not present any evidences or sources to support your claims.

Comment: The link summarizes the hadith and Shaykh Abdul Nasirs talk on the subject. And they're linked at the bottom as well.